# Fetching access token from a Spring Oauth2 server

Tags: spring, spring-security

For days now I've been trying to set up a simple Spring Oauth2 server, that supports clients with authorization_code grant type. My use case is this: I want to get the access token from such a server Postman. That's it.

Here's what my code looks like:

`pom.xml`

```
...
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
...

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`application.yml`

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      authorizationserver:
        client:
          client-1:
            registration:
              client-id: client
              client-secret: client-secret
              client-authentication-methods:
                - client_secret_basic
              authorization-grant-types:
                - authorization_code
                - refresh_token
                - client_credentials
              redirect-uris:
                - https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
              scopes:
                - user.read
                - user.write
                - openid
```

Main class:

```
package com.demos.spring.auth_resource.server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringAuthResourceServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringAuthResourceServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().roles("admin", "user").username("john").password("pw").build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

}
```

From Postman I am trying to get a token using the following config:

[postman config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKepz.png)

Once I submit the form with "Get New Access Token" a pop up form opens, I log in, and the authorization code gets redirected, but when the oauth2/token request is sent I don't get the access token. Instead I get redirected to the login page again, as you can see in the logs bellow:

[postman logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0y3A.png)

My expectation here was to get the access token that I can further use to access resources. I've tried fetching access token from other Oauth2 servers such as Spotify- and that worked as expected. Therefore, I'm inclined to believe there's something wrong with my Spring Oauth2 Server.

Comment: why havn't you read your DEBUG logs?